# Why won't my sqlite3 code work in python3?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I keep getting an `sql.OperationError`, why?

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3 as sql

money = sql.connect("money_in_changejar.db")
money.execute("CREATE TABLE money (total FLOAR NOT NULL, pennies INTEGER NOT NULL, nickles INTEGER NOT NULL, dimes INTEGER NOT NULL, quarters INTEGER NOT NULL)")
money.close()
```

Comment: Actually, your full error is `sqlite3.OperationalError: table money already exists`. I copy pasted your code, it works perfectly fine. But as expected, since it already exists, you will get this `OperationalError` exception. You should add some kind of condition to check if the table already exists if you are going to be running this several times.

Comment: It would be nice to post your error message..

Comment: @IronFist I'm fairly sure it is what I mentioned in my comment. The code works the first time, but as expected, not the second, because it already exists.

Comment: @idjaw, right, I asked just for the sake of a properly asked question.

Comment: @IronFist Oh, yes. Absolutely! The question is clearly missing the necessary information. I should not have had to run this myself to find out *what* error it was.